# Win7 64/32 bits c# dll doubt

Tags: c#, dll, winapi, win64

is it possible to build a c# dll and tlb files in a win7 64 bits computer and make it work in a win7 32bits computer?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:
I am using a c++ dll that calls the .tlb file generated in my c# COM interop dll proj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building a pure C# DLL, you won't end up with a TLB file. Build it with a target of "Any CPU" and it will work fine on 32 or 64 bit computers.

You'd normally only need a TLB file if you're exporting a COM component (as I understand it) - do you need to do that?

Comment: yes, I am using a c++ dll that calls the .tlb file generated in my c# COM interop dll.

Comment: @aF: Okay... that makes it harder and somewhat out of my realm of expertise. Is the C++ DLL built as 32-bit or 64-bit? In the bigger picture, is this going to be running as a 64-bit process on 64-bit machines, and a 32-bit process on 32-bit machines?

Comment: is it possible to be a single process that works on both machines? Or it has to be one for each?

Comment: @aF: I believe that if you have 32-bit binaries across the board, it should work fine using WoW64. I think the difficulty comes if you try to mix them within the same process. I should emphasize that I have no experience of this though, so I could be completely wrong.